# How do I remove (only) an asterisk from the inner text of an HTML <td> component?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html-table, innerhtml

I'm trying to figure out how to remove/replace an "asterisk" from the innerHTML of a `<td>` component.

I have a  which contains same free text and an input control.
Assume in the following sample that `<td>` == this

```
$(this)[0].innerHTML
"*&nbsp;<input name="ctl00$MainContent$TxnDate" type="text" id="TxnDate" class="DetailTextBox dvFieldTypeDateTime dvRequiredField hasDatepicker validationFailed" style="width:250px;">&nbsp;Required Field"
```

How do I replace/remove the asterisk from the inner HTML?

```
$(this)[0].innerHTML[0]
```

I have tried:

```
$(this)[0].innerHTML.replace(/\*/g, '');
```

But that seems to delete the current contents of my input control.

Comment: try like `$(this).eq(0).html($(this).html().replace(/\*/g, ''))`.

Comment: I wouldn't recommend doing it this way because it will update any attribute values with `*` in it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The regular expression you have is correct, you need to assign the changed html back to the `innerHTML`, check it [here](http://jsfiddle.net/g61ewyfm/1/)

```
this.innerHTML = this.innerHTML.replace(/\*/g, '');
```

After assigning the changed `html` back you wont get `*`

[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/g61ewyfm/4/)

**Edit**

If you want to replace only in first node i.e. `*&nbsp;` then you only need `firstChild`

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/g61ewyfm/6/)**

```
firstChild = this.firstChild;
firstChild.nodeValue = firstChild.nodeValue.replace(/\*/g, '');
```

To exclude the input you can use `nodeType` to apply the replace on only text elements those are child of the html element you have by iterating through the childs.

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/g61ewyfm/5/)**

```
function removeAsterisk(htmlParentObject)
{
    nextsib = htmlParentObject.firstChild;
    while(nextsib != null)
    {
        if(nextsib.nodeType === 3);
              nextsib.nodeValue = nextsib.nodeValue.replace(/\*/g, '');
        nextsib = nextsib.nextSibling;    
    }
}
```

Comment: why `$(this)[0].innerHTML`? `this.innerHTML` will do

Comment: Adil: I know to reassign back to original innerHTML to update the value. The question really is the removal of the asterisk. The replace with the regular expression seems to clear out any value contained in my <input> control as well.

Answer (score 0):

When you are using jquery you can say like this

```
$(this).eq(0).html($(this).html().replace(/\*/g, ''))
```

Comment: Once again, this solution clears the contents of the input control that is also contained within <td>

Answer (score 0):

Try this example:

**script**

```
var ps = document.getElementsByTagName('p');
var l = ps.length;
if (l--) do {
    ps[l].innerHTML = ps[l].innerHTML.replace(/\*/g, '');
} while (l--);
```

**html**

```
<p>hi there*, everyone* !</p>
<p>LOL* !</p>
```

**output**

```
hi there, everyone !

LOL !
```

Answer (score 0):

try this solution:

```
$('td.validationFailed').contents().filter(function() { 
    return this.nodeType == 3 && this.wholeText.indexOf('*') > -1; 
})
.remove();
```

### [Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/fiddleyetu/S2Vdt/)

Via [**user3558931**](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3558931/user3558931)